# Form Send Button Will Not Validate Form Input Text Fields When Asked to Continue Form Submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form on my webpage at [www.thetotempole.ca](http://thetotempole.ca/formproject.html/) and for example it has a postal/zip code text field and if the user does not type in a correct zip/postal code the form will display a popup saying that the zip/postal code is not valid. Although, when the user hits submit I want it to display a confirm pop up asking if they really want to send the form. This interferes with the input text field validations (I.E the zip postal code validator) some how and ends up not validating the text fields at all. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!!

HTML:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         function validate()
         {
            var myform = document.getElementById("form1");
            myform.fname.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.lname.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.address.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.city.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.provstate.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.country.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            myform.postalzip.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            console.log("form object: " + myform);
            if (myform.fname.value == "")
            {
               alert("First Name must have a value");
               myform.fname.focus();
               myform.fname.style.backgroundColor = "red";
               return false;
            }
            if (myform.lname.value == "")
            {
               alert("Last Name must have a value");
               myform.lname.focus();
               return false;
            }
            if (myform.address.value == "")
            {
               alert("Address must have a value");
               myform.address.focus();
               return false;
            }
            if (myform.postalzip.value == "")
            {
               alert("Postal/Zip Code must have a value");
               myform.postalzip.focus();
               return false;
            }
            else
            {
               //var regex = new RegExp();
               var regex = /^([a-z]\d[a-z]\s?\d[a-z]\d)|(\d{5}(\s?\d{4})?)$/i;
               myform.postalzip.value.toUpperCase();
               if (!regex.test(myform.postalzip.value))
               {
                  alert("Postal/Zip Code has invalid format");
                  myform.postalzip.focus();
                  return false;

               }
            }

            return true;
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="form1">
         First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
         Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
         Address:<input type="text" name="address" /><br />
         City:<input type="text" name="city" /><br />
         Province/State:<input type="text" name="provstate" /><br />
         Country:<input type="text" name="country" /><br />
         Postal/Zip Code:<input style="text-transform: uppercase;" type="text" name="postalzip" /><br />
         <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to continue?')" value="Send" />
         <input type="reset" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to reset?')" value="Reset" />

      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your link is broken : (. Looks like you're not calling `validate()` in the posted code snippet...

Comment: Unless I am missing something, I don't see where you ever actually call the validate function. From what I see, the easiest thing here is to create two unique functions for the two onclick events. Then, handle the confirm inside the function (as the confirm returns a value, you can perform further operations based on the return).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick-fix:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return (validate() && confirm('Do you really want to continue?'))" value="Send" />
```